# JS & HTML: I cannot create unique HTML Input Buttons using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am a complete newbie to programming and I am trying to create a simple form that takes input, creates a list of 'users' and generates a button next to a list of names that allows you to expand their info in a little box beneath the list.

```
let friendList = []
let friendname = []
let frienddex = ''



class Person {
    constructor(fname, lname, age, job, gender) {
    this.fname = fname
    this.lname = lname
    this.age = age
    this.gender = gender
    this.job = job
    }
    
    
}   

function generate2(x) {
    let ppl = friendname.indexOf(x)
    console.log(ppl)
    document.getElementById("p_name").innerHTML = `Name: ${friendList[ppl]["fname"]} ${friendList[ppl]["lname"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_age").innerHTML = `Age: ${friendList[ppl]["age"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_occupation").innerHTML = `Job: ${friendList[ppl]["job"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_gender").innerHTML =`Gender: ${friendList[ppl]["gender"]}`
}

function submit() {
        
        let person = new Person(document.getElementById("fname").value, 
        document.getElementById("lname").value,
        document.getElementById("age").value, 
        document.getElementById("job").value, 
        document.getElementById("gender").value)
        
        friendList.push(person)
        friendname.push(person.fname)
        
        console.log(friendList)
        console.log(friendname)
}



function generate() {
        document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML = " "
        
        for (friend in friendList)
        document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML += `${friendList[friend]["fname"]} ${friendList[friend]["lname"]} <input type="button" onClick="generate2(friendList[friend]['fname'])" value='View Profile'><br> `
        console.log(friend)
        
}
```

but when I use this code:

```
function generate() {
        document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML = " "

        for (friend in friendList)
        document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML += `${friendList[friend]["fname"]} ${friendList[friend]["lname"]} <input type="button" onClick="generate2(friendList[friend]['fname'])" value='View Profile'><br> `
        console.log(friend)

}
```

It only generates a series of buttons with the first index (0) instead of each button containing the index of that iteration. I have been tinkering with this for hours and I cannot get it to work. Could someone school me here?

EDIT: I was trying to keep this shorter. Here is the HTML as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<header>
</header>
<style>

    body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: fixed;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="field">
            <p id="flist"><span id="button"></span></P>
            
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
            
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
            
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="number" id="age"><br>
            
            <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
            <input type="text" id="job"><br>
            
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select id="gender">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select><br>
            
            <input type="button" id="submit" onClick="submit()" value="Submit">
            
            <label for="gen"></label>
            <input type="button" id="gen" onClick="generate()" value="Generate List">
            
        </div>
        
        <div id='profile'>
            <h1 id ='p_name'></h1>
            <h2 id='p_age'></h2>
            <h2 id='p_occupation'></h2>
            <h2 id='p_gender'></h2>
        </div>
</body>
<canvas>
</canvas>
<script src='05_24_JS.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be useful to see your html code too.

Answer (score 0):

The `friend` variable/reference changes each type the loop runs so when `generate2()` is called the `friend` variable refers to the current value of `friend` (after the loop has finished). You can fix it by grabbing the value from `friend` each iteration of the loop and hardcoding that value in the generated html.

```js
let friendList = []
let friendname = []
let frienddex = ''

class Person {
    constructor(fname, lname, age, job, gender) {
        this.fname = fname
        this.lname = lname
        this.age = age
        this.gender = gender
        this.job = job
    }
}

function generate2(x) {
    let ppl = friendname.indexOf(x)
    console.log(ppl)
    document.getElementById("p_name").innerHTML = `Name: ${friendList[ppl]["fname"]} ${friendList[ppl]["lname"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_age").innerHTML = `Age: ${friendList[ppl]["age"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_occupation").innerHTML = `Job: ${friendList[ppl]["job"]}`
    document.getElementById("p_gender").innerHTML = `Gender: ${friendList[ppl]["gender"]}`
}

function submit() {

    let person = new Person(document.getElementById("fname").value,
        document.getElementById("lname").value,
        document.getElementById("age").value,
        document.getElementById("job").value,
        document.getElementById("gender").value)

    friendList.push(person)
    friendname.push(person.fname)

    console.log(friendList)
    console.log(friendname)
}

console.log(typeof(submit));


function generate() {
    document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML = " "

    for (friend in friendList) {
        document.getElementById('flist').innerHTML += `${friendList[friend]["fname"]} ${friendList[friend]["lname"]} <input type="button" onClick="generate2(friendList['${friend}']['fname'])" value='View Profile'><br> `
        console.log(friend)
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<header>
</header>
<style>

    body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: fixed;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="field">
            <p id="flist"><span id="button"></span></P>
            
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
            
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
            
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="number" id="age"><br>
            
            <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
            <input type="text" id="job"><br>
            
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select id="gender">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select><br>
            
            <input type="button" id="submit" onClick="submit()" value="Submit">
            
            <label for="gen"></label>
            <input type="button" id="gen" onClick="generate()" value="Generate List">
            
        </div>
        
        <div id='profile'>
            <h1 id ='p_name'></h1>
            <h2 id='p_age'></h2>
            <h2 id='p_occupation'></h2>
            <h2 id='p_gender'></h2>
        </div>
</body>
<canvas>
</canvas>
<script src='05_24_JS.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I go about grabbing the current friend value after each iteration? Or how is the best way to do that. I'm aiming to develop better habits/techniques

Comment: I changed `onClick="generate2(friendList[friend]['fname'])"` to `onClick="generate2(friendList['${friend}']['fname'])"` in the code above. If you run the code snippet above you should find that creating two users and then generating the list results in a couple of View Profile buttons that each shows the correct user when clicked.

Comment: And on the subject of better habits/techniques, I'd suggest giving each user created an `id` and use that the identify which user's profile to view  instead of first name (otherwise you could end up with multiple users with the same first name and so whichever View Profile button you clicked it would always show the first user with that first name).

Comment: I notice you've created a class `Person` which is fine but if I were writing it I'd just use an object. Javascript is not strongly typed so you don't need a class. Again, nothing wrong with using a class, just not required.

Comment: One more little piece of advice. I'd suggest using `document.querySelector` exclusively (instead of `document.getElementById`). Nothing wrong with `document.getElementById` so long as all the elements you want to select have an `id` but I like `document.querySelector` because it lets you use css queries to specify which element you want which is more flexible. For example, instead of  `document.getElementById('age')` you would say `document.querySelector('#age')` (`#` is the css selector prefix that is used when selecting based on `id`). Nothing wrong with your way I just like `querySelector`.